# super.paintComponent() isn't working as expected

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to draw a shape multiple times inside a JPanel to mimic an animation (a moving shape across it). The problem is that the shape is being redrawn and thus appearing on the screen multiple times on different places, when all i pretend is that only one shape is visible at a time when it's being redrawn.

The method super.paintComponent() should be responsible for repainting JPanel's background and thus, only one shape should be visible when the redrawing is being performed.

I have the following code (**it has been reduced/simplified for the sake of simplicity and better understanding**):

```
public class Animated_Shape_Test extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    {
        new Animated_Shape_Test();
    }

    public Animated_Shape_Test() throws IOException
    {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.setLocation(new Point(430, 150));
        this.setTitle("Database Launcher v1.0");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);

        DBPanel panel = new DBPanel();

        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

final class DBPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{   
    int musicShapePosX = 85;
    int musicShapePosY = 100;
    int SEGMENT_SHAPE_LENGTH = 50;
    int SHAPE_HEIGHT = 10;
    float SHAPE_SPEED = 7.5f; 

    CustomShapeButton musicShapeButton = new CustomShapeButton(musicShapePosX, musicShapePosY, SEGMENT_SHAPE_LENGTH, SHAPE_HEIGHT);

    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = null;

    protected DBPanel() throws IOException
    {   
        shapes = new ArrayList();

        shapes.add(musicShapeButton);

        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        startThread();
    }

    public void startThread()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);

        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2.setColor(getBackground().darker());
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.draw(musicShapeButton);
    }

    public void delay(int milliseconds)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            delay(35);
            animateButtonShapeMusic();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void animateButtonShapeMusic()
    {
        if (musicShapePosY < 228)
        {
            musicShapePosY = (int)(musicShapePosY + SHAPE_SPEED);    

            musicShapeButton.drawShape(musicShapePosX, musicShapePosY, SEGMENT_SHAPE_LENGTH, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting several shapes being redrawn across the screen (animation).
I expect a single shape being redrawn across the screen (animation).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there, what you're asking for isn't totally clear.  You're describing both the undesired and the desired behaviors as animation.  Can you clarify?

Comment: As long as you're modifying the program, get rid of the applet capabilities.  And please provide a [MCVE] to help demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you WJS. I've made those changes on the code. It is much cleaner now.

Comment: Yes, n8, thank you for you reply. In fact, both are animations. One is the desirable one (the one i'm not getting), the other is the undesirable (the one i'm getting).